# What does the word 「なりそこなった」 mean?

Tags: meaning, compound-verbs

Here is the sentence including the word.

> 自分がチャンピオンに**なりそこなった**もんだから　このおれにゆめをたくそうってわけだな。

Comment: How is this a translation request? Asking about a piece of a sentence which can't be understood by a dictionary lookup feels well within the scope of this website.

Comment: OP has asked many questions [exactly in the same way](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9559/george?tab=questions). I understand that this question can appear as too easy and uninteresting to some, but I'm kind of surprised at this inconsistent response from the community. It's always good for OP to show his own translation effort, anyway...

Comment: I think the inconsistent response is partially due to whether someone initiates the close vote or not -- if someone does, it ends up in the review queues which makes it far more likely to get closed than if no one touched it in the first place.

Comment: But either way, I don't think we should be closing questions just because the answer is obvious to someone who knows Japanese...

Answer (score 3):

"[連用形] + 損【そこ】なう" is a common combination which means "fail to [verb]". See definition #4 of [this entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/130437/m0u/).

チャンピオンになりそこなう = to fail to become a champion

Comment: te-formじゃなくて連用形・・・　-１の理由かどうかわからんけど・・

Comment: あ、te-formと連用形は同じ意味だと思ってたんですが、「te-formは連用形の一部」なんですか。

Comment: この例だと、「なる」の「て形」っていうと、「 **なっ**て」になるんで、「なっ」になっちゃうと、「な**り** +そこなう」にならないんで・・。多分こんな感じかな、と-> http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/contents/explanation/043.html

Comment: 「連用形には masu-form と te-form がある」という理解で合ってます?

Comment: テ形は「て」（か「で」）が入っている形だと思います（例：「なって」）。連用形は「〜ます」・「〜たい」・「〜うる」などの前に来る形です（例：「なり」）。実は、テ形の中に音便化した連用形があります：「× **なり**て」→「 **なっ**て」。